# Kubuntu 18.04 freezes when running for about an hour

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 18.04, kubuntu, freeze

I have installed this as my first Linux system about a month ago. When I run it for about an hour, it freezes.

Sometimes lasts longer like two full days, but just once.
It freezes when I freshly boot it up and let it sit, as a test.

I never ran it long enough for it to freeze on me while I'm using it, so I only know that it freezes when it is idle.

I went through a few funky processes to get the system running. I dual boot with windows 10. Once after setup, I decided I want to Linux partition to be bigger, so I used `GParted` to make it bigger.

This ended up corrupting the dual boot process, I forgot exactly how I fixed it but I think I ran the install disc, used it as the "try it" option and entered some command line.

Once the dual boot started working perfectly, I was comfortable enough that I could finally leave it alone for hours, so this is when I first started dealing with the freezes.

I have tried numerous things, like updating `nvidia` drivers, re-installing packages using command lines.

The freezing never stops. When it freezes, the entire machine is frozen. `Hotkey` to kill `xserver` will not work, or anything else.

**My hardware:**

- gtx 1070
- 16 gb ram
- i7 7700k
- Gigabyte GA-Z170X-UD3 Ultra motherboard

I installed using a disc. Should I try re-installing? 
And try using a thumb drive?

Is this likely a hardware issue?